# Exclude project\folder from "Navigate Files" in IntelliJ

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, intellij-13

I'm developing a Grails application with IntelliJ. Many time happens this: When i try to find a file by this shortcut :

```
Ctrl+Shift+N
```

IntelliJ find the source file and the 'compiled' (same) file (Because grails plugin imported into a grail app, copy entirelly his folder).

There is a way to hide project-files from "Navigation File" functionality?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can right click the plugin folder in the project tree and mark it as "Excluded":

[image: Exclude directory]

Comment: Only then it will be also excluded from auto completion. So if I exclude `bower_components`, IntelliJ won't know auto complete Bootstrap's tags.